# /var file buildup

Tags: file

I'm a (semi-new) Mac developer. I've been working on a component to my app that - in order to function properly - needs to download a fairly large file from the internet. I thought this file would be stored in memory (and would be automatically removed once the app no longer needed it via ARC), but it's actually stored in the /var folder. I've been running and debugging this component for numerous days, which means roughly 20GB of unnecessary files have built up. Of course, I quickly changed my code to remove this file once it's no longer needed, but now I have a big, single 20GB file on my system that I must get rid of. I have a 64GB MBA, so I need all the space I can get. This is the path: /private/var/folders/9r/s6cf1dsj0_30tbz14vmhxj1r0000gn/T

Any ideas as to how I can hunt these files down and remove them? I know the system keeps some important files in the /var folder, so I'm really hesitant to just drag it to the trash. I also have a whole bunch of custom stuff on my system, so I really don't want to do a clean install if I don't have to. Any ideas? I appreciate your time.

Comment: what is the filename within the folder you identified? Also have you rebooted recently, it may be that it is cleared out as a temp file on reboot.

Comment: A reboot didn't help. Fortunately, it looks like the system has gone through and removed most of the file. The file is only 7.7 GB now. I suspect the system will continue to clean it out within the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they system is going through and removing parts of this file. Over time, I notice this file getting smaller and smaller. No tools or re-installs necessary.